# ¿ Es posible realizar cambio de esquema de base de datos al momento de login sobre Laravel?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

Necesito usar varios esquemas de base de datos sobre un proyecto de Laravel, usando los mismos models y tablas en los esquemas, solo necesito segmentar la información, los esquemas de base de datos están sobre el mismo servidor de MySQL.

Contexto:
Necesito un **login** que dependiendo una opción se conecte con una base de datos de acuerdo a la opción elegida.

Sera que Laravel tendrá esa flexibilidad?, he buscado sobre el tema pero no encuentro referencias.

Comment: Tu pregunta es demasiado amplia y carece de un [mcve], por favor lee [ask], te diría que si quieres hacer *switch* de una base de datos a otra claro que si se puede, lee [aqui](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent#database-connections)

Comment: Seguramente quieres usar el mismo sistema con bases de datos diferentes, yo lo hice con php en un momento, pero de una forma muy compleja, no podes usar la misma bd, y poner una bandera a que cliente pertenece la fila? algo así como idCliente o IdEmpresa.